Computing Auslander Reiten Quivers using Computer Algebra software
I was wondering if there is any algebra software that can be used to compute the Auslander Reiten graph for a given path algebra, and find out related details like the exterior algebra structure etc.

There is an applet written by Jan Geuenich available on Bill Crawley-Boevey's website that allows to "knit" (at least parts) of the Auslander-Reiten quiver of a given algebra, starting from input about the projectives: https://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/~wcrawley/#knitting

Thank you for your help
